# Find out if WP7 is in silent mode

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Does anyone know how to find out if a WP7 is on silent/vibrate mode in a silverlight app?  I need to fix my app from playing sound effects when it is on vibrate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Will MediaPlayer.IsMuted work?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.ismuted.aspx

Here is the discussion that pointed me there where they suggest that it should be usable from silverlight. 
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/64166/392704.aspx

Comment: hm doesn't seem like it is set.  I guess I'll have to add an option to disable sounds.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see by checking these classes : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info(VS.92).aspx there is currently no way in getting the devices sound settings, not even in Mango, and not in NoDo, too. Sorry.